# How to get refresh of image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, cache-control

I try to load image dynamically. The XAML is:

The code to load image is: (it is fired by button click event in code behind)

```
Image myimage = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url)) };
this.myPlayer.Content = myimage;
```

The URL point to a site for the image. Suppose I have image with URL like:

```
"http://mysite/myfolder/my.jpg"
```

Then I run the app, click on the button, I can get the image and display it in UI without problem.

Then I override the image file on server with the same name, then click on the button again, the image is not refreshed. I need to reload the whole SL app for the new image display.
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to resolve that issue is to put a random number at the end of the image URL.

```cs
Random random = new Random();
int randomValue = random.Next(1000000);  // will return value between 0 & 1,000,000
string base = "http://mysite/myfolder/my.jpg";
string url = base + "?unused=" + randomValue;
//Note url now equals: "http://mysite/myfolder/my.jpg?unused=####"

Image myimage = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url)) };
this.myPlayer.Content = myimage;
```

This works because the web server will automatically ignore the `?unused=` part appended to the image name.

Each time you roll through this function, you should receive a new random value from `random.Next(...)` which will indicate a "new" image request and will bypass any caching that may be going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the caching behavior using the `BitmapImage.CacheOption` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx

You could try `OnLoad` before `None`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx